# SharePoint 2010 function

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to SharePoint 2010 and I use it for managing our dept. documents.  I created some document libraries and a folder (gather the history docs by time) to manage the documents.  Recently I had a request from my manager that he wanted to view the newest documents from those document libraries in a simple page.  The total requests have to include the info of date uploaded, the user who uploaded it, frequency of changes etc.  I am using a workflow to resolve it, but it is hard to me now.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I might understand you wrong but you could do this to create a webpart-page with a view to each lists newest documents

- Create a List WebPart referring to your DocLib
- Create a Listview that orders by created or edited date in ascending order

Here is some more information about ListViews:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1622404&seqNum=14

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Hi Tom ,Thanks a lot. I will try it first!! Best Regards